# How to sort content in Views by menu weight

Tags: 7, views

I have a D7 [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) view which delivers a number of nodes. I would like them to be sorted based on the weight that their relevant menu items have.

I would like to avoid the fine module [DraggableViews](https://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) or any additional weight field for that matter.

How could this be accomplished?

Relevant pages: https://drupal.org/node/313140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: Referencing a user contributed module: [Views menu sort](https://drupal.org/comment/5812780#comment-5812780) which at #48 has a D7 version. I have not tested this but others report success.

2: Another method you could use is to use a PHP field in your view like in this article on [tappetyclick.com](http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2013/01/07/how-order-drupal-view-node-menu-weight#.UyG_bl5RHVk). (I have used this method before)

3: Or you can use the module [menu node views](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) which requires [menu node](https://drupal.org/project/menu_node).

Answer (score 4):

A quick and simple solution without the need of extra modules might be to:

1. alter a view result before rendering using [uasort()](http://php.net/uasort),
2. use sort callback `YOURMODULE_sort_view_on_menu_link_weight()` and
3. use helper function `YOURMODULE_build_menu_by_path()` to create an array with menu link data keyed on node paths.

NB: This snippet:

1. assumes the menu the nodes are referenced from is the main menu (one can change the menu key `main-menu`),
2. does not take menu depth or Views pagination into account and
3. overwrites any sorting done by Views.

---

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 *
 * - Sort view result based on menu link weights.
 */
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'YOURVIEWID') {
    uasort($view->result, 'YOURMODULE_sort_view_on_menu_link_weight');
  }
}

/**
 * uasort() callback to sort a view result on menu links weights.
 */
function YOURMODULE_sort_view_on_menu_link_weight($a, $b) {
  $menu_by_path = &drupal_static(__FILE__, array());

  // Get $menu_by_path once.
  if (empty($menu_by_path)) {
    YOURMODULE_build_menu_by_path(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu'), $menu_by_path);
  }

  // Get menu item weights by node ID.
  $weight_a = isset($menu_by_path['node/' . $a->nid]) ? (int) $menu_by_path['node/' . $a->nid]['weight'] : 0;
  $weight_b = isset($menu_by_path['node/' . $b->nid]) ? (int) $menu_by_path['node/' . $b->nid]['weight'] : 0;

  // Return sort value.
  return $weight_a == $weight_b ? 0 : ($weight_a < $weight_b ? -1 : 1);
}

/**
 * Helper function to get an array with menu link data, keyed by menu link path.
 */
function YOURMODULE_build_menu_by_path($menu, &$menu_by_path, $depth = 0) {
  // Iterate through menu items.
  foreach ($menu as $key => $menu_item) {
    // If menu item links to a node.
    if (strpos($menu_item['link']['link_path'], 'node/') === 0) {
      // Create $menu_by_path entry, store depth and weight.
      $menu_by_path[$menu_item['link']['link_path']] = array(
        'depth' => $depth,
        'weight' => $menu_item['link']['weight'],
      );
    }

    // If menu item has children.
    if (!empty($menu_item['below'])) {
      // Call this function on the menu item's submenu.
      YOURMODULE_build_menu_by_path($menu_item['below'], $menu_by_path, $depth+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The module [Views Menu Node Children Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_menu_children_filter) can also sort by menu weight since version 7.x-1.0-rc3.

Comment: This is the most straight-forward way to do this. Just install the module and add the sort criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the Views PHP module.

A PHP function is required in order to retrieve the relevant menu item weight:

```
function get_menu_weight($nodeID) {
  $weight = 0;
  $query = "SELECT weight FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path = :path AND hidden < 1";
  $args = array(':path' => 'node/' . $nodeID);
  $result = db_query($query, $args);
  if ($result->rowCount() > 0)
    $weight = $result->fetch()->weight;
  return $weight;
}
```

This function can reside in a `template.php` file or a custom module.

Then in the view under concern:

- Add a *Content: Nid* field to the list of fields and exclude it from display
- Add a *Global: PHP* field to the list of fields and exclude it from display
- In the *Value code* set `return get_menu_weight($row->nid);` (*without* php tags)
- In the *Output code* set `<?php print $value; ?>` (*with* PHP tags)
- Add a *Global: PHP* field to the *sort* fields of the view and specify:

  ```
  if ($row1->php < $row2->php) return -1; 
  else return 1;
  ```

Source: http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2013/01/07/how-order-drupal-view-node-menu-weight#.UyG1St8hGb4